# Is this a good structure for my jQuery scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, idioms

I want to keep my scripts organized in one .js file for all my site (I have a mess right now), something like namespaces and classes in C#...

```
(function ($) {

    //private variables
    $.divref = $("#divReference");

    //Namespaces
    window.MySite = {};
    window.MySite.Home = {};
    window.MySite.Contact = {};

    //Public function / method
    window.MySite.Home.Init = function(params){
        alert("Init");

        MySite.Home.PrivateFunction();

        $.divref.click(function(){
            alert("click");
        });
    };

    //private function / method
    MySite.Home.PrivateFunction = function(){
        alert("Private");
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Is this an idiomatic layout in jQuery and JScript?

Comment: Your approach to creating private variables is wrong.  You're attaching them to the $ object, which will exist after your code has finished executing.  You want a closure for that.

Comment: @g.d.d.c That would make a fine answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more how I would implement the pattern you are trying to do:

```
// MySite.Home Extension
window.MySite = 
    (function ($, root) {

        //private variables
        var $divref = $("#divReference");

        //private function / method
        var privateFunction = function(){
            alert("Private");
        };        

        root.Home = {};

        // Public variable
        root.Home.prop = "Click"

        //Public function / method
        root.Home.Init = function(params){
            alert("Init");

            private();

            $divref.click(function(){
                alert(root.Home.prop);
            });
        };

        return root;

    })(jQuery, window.MySite || {} );   

// MySite.Contact Extension
window.MySite = 
    (function ($, root) {

        root.Contact = {};

        // More stuff for contact

        return root;

    })(jQuery, window.MySite || {} );
```

The first change is splitting each "namespace" into its own Module pattern, so private variables wont bleed from namespace to namespace (if you do intend them to be private to the namespace, which would be more C# esque). Second is rather than accessing `window.MySite`, pass in the object that you want to extend (in this case I'm calling it `root`). This will give you some flexibility.

Your *private methods* weren't really private. To make a private method, you just want to make a function var that it bound in the closure, but not assigned to a property on the externally visible object. Lastly, you probably don't want to use `$.somegarbage`. Like mentioned in a comment, you are adding a property to the `$` object, which will still be there when the closure is done. If you wanted something close, I would just use `$somegarbage` which some people seem to like to do, but any variable name will work for private variables, just as long as the variable is bound in the closures scope (not somewhere else)

You are on the right track...

Answer (score 3):

I'll go ahead and post my comment as an answer, though I'm not 100% it addresses your questions about c# namespaces and their parallels in JavaScript (I'm no c# programmer).  You're not actually creating private variables because you're attaching them to the `$` Object that will exist after this function finishes.  If you want private variables you need to use a closure.  Those look something like this:

```
var myObject = function () {
  var innerVariable = 'some private value';

  return {
    getter: function () {
      return innerVariable;
    }
  }
}()
```

If you attempt to access `myObject.innerVariable` it will return `undefined` but if you call `myObject.getter()` it will return the value correctly.  This concept is one you will want to read up on in JavaScript, and for programming in general.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't notice that. They are public variables then-. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you might want to read up on the [Module pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) ([more](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)) and closures in javascript to prevent polluting the global namespace.